# Angular 4 location.path to navigate between components

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have recently started a project with angular 4 an typescripts. All is going well until one point:

I have a need to create routing principles. For this I have created routing in My `App.Module.ts`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      {path: 'thanks', component: ThanksComponent} //, canActivate: [AuthGuard]

    ])
```

In angular js, in order to pass from one route to another we used `routeConfig` and then just used in controller:

```
$location.path("/roue");
```

In order to navigate.

My big idea is to navigate between components just like I used navigation in angular js.
How can I navigate between components in Angular 4?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sajeetharan *almost* got it.

import the Router with

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Inject it in your component

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Now you have several ways to call it

```
this.router.navigate(['thanks']); // Array of routes
this.router.navigateByUrl('/thanks'); // Absolute path
this.router.navigate(['thanks', 1]); // route corresponding to thanks/1, useful for params
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import **`Router`** and use

**`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`**

```
constructor(private _router: Router)
this.router.navigate("/thanks");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

`[routerLink]="['/roue']"` in your html

or in your component :

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private router: Router,
) { }

goToRoue(){
    this.router.navigate(['/roue']);
}
```

Hope it helps!